# display image tag in CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I have writter code to display result with one image column. somehow it is giving me error

I have written code like this.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'photo-grid',
'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
//'filter' => $model,
'columns' => array(
    'id',
    array(
            'name'=>'user_id',
            'value'=>'GxHtml::valueEx($data->user)',
            'filter'=>GxHtml::listDataEx(User::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
            ),
    array(
            'name'=>'regulation_id',
            'value'=>'GxHtml::valueEx($data->regulation)',
            'filter'=>GxHtml::listDataEx(Regulation::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
            ),
    //'photo_img',
    array(
            'name' => 'Photo Img',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => CHtml::image(Yii::app()->controller->createUrl('photo/loadImage', array('id'=>$model->id)),"",array('width'=>50, 'height'=>50)), 
            ),
    array(
        'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

)); ?>

can any one help me how to display image in CGridView?

Comment: what is the error? why did you comment `'type'=>'raw'`?

Comment: yes I have written 'type'=>'raw' but it is giving me syntex error.  
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pte\framework\base\CComponent.php(607) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: i think pentium10 has answered this correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no $model->id on that level

You need to change that into $data, and make sure it is a string, that will be evaluated later when the cell renders (if you leave as non-string, that means it is evaluated before your grid is created)

```
'value' => 'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->controller->createUrl(\'photo/loadImage\', array(\'id\'=>$data->id)),"",array(\'width\'=>50, \'height\'=>50))',
```

Comment: can I open that image in light box. Right now I can open light box on click of image but It displays me binary format. is there any solution of this?

Comment: sounds to me that you have something with the script that returns the image

Comment: I have stored image in binary format in my database table field (kept field type as LONGBLOB). So in my lightbox, binary string of image gets open. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it's working:

```
array(        
    'name'=>'Image_name_large',
    'value'=>'CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/uploads/vehiclesimages/".$data->Image_name_large,
     "",
     array(\'width\'=>100, \'height\'=>100))',
     'type'=>'raw',
),
```